# org-agenda-prefix-format change file name

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Can you change categories based on their files? For example there is a file `todo.org` in an `orgzly` folder and another `todo.org` in a local folder. Could you change org-agenda-prefix-format (or something else) so that entries in these org files show up in org-agenda as `orgzly` and `local` instead of both showing up as `todo`?
[image]

Comment: Add `#+CATEGORY: orgzly` at the top of the first one and `#+CATEGORY: local` at the top of the second one.

Comment: Thanks @NickD, that worked. Strange, I always append new entries to the beginning of the .org file in orgzly (to have them show up at the top instead of scrolling to the bottom), so I thought that adding `#+CATEGORY: orgzly` will get overwritten by the subsequent entries. It turns out it gets picked up by org-agenda even if it's added in the middle. Good stuff!

Comment: Keywords have global scope, no matter where they are defined. But it's best to keep them visible, so adding them to the beginning of the file is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Execute `C-h v org-agenda-prefix-format RET` in Emacs, you will find
the answer. Actually, you will find that you can use any elisp
expression you want:

```
  %(expression) Eval EXPRESSION and replace the control string
                by the result
```

Based on that, you can use the below expression to replace `%c` there,
it will serve your need:
`%(file-name-nondirectory (directory-file-name (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name))))`

Comment: That's not enough to do what is asked: you  have to conditionally make the category `orgzly` or `local` depending on the pathname. But as mentioned in my comment, it is simpler to set the category of each file explicitily.